# How do disabled button in Script onClick even in mvc 4 razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I got a issue with `JavaScript` when user click on add button in table the add button will disabled which is working but not properly. it was giving issue with some Id like user click on `Id="rbutton_1"` then it will disable all button with Id `Id="rbutton_10"`, `Id="rbutton_11"` which i want to fix My JavaScript.

**Here is a HTML Table view**

```
@foreach (var item in this.Model.CartList)
{
       <tr>
       <td class="i"><img class="i" src="@item.IconUrl"></td>
       <td>@item.ServiceName</td>
       <td><span class="fa fa-inr"></span><span>@Convert.ToInt32(@item.TotalPrice)</span></td>
       <td>
         <a href="#" id="rbutton + @item.ServiceId" onclick="onRemove(event, @item.ServiceId)" class="btn btn-danger" style="padding: 4px 5px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
       </td>
  </tr>  
}
```

Here is a `Script on click event` below:

```
function onClick(e, Id) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = '@Url.Action("CartAdd", "Home")/' + Id;
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $(".ref").load("Detail .ref");
        $(".t").find("a[id*='rbutton_" + Id + "']").attr("disabled", "disabled").attr("onClick", "this.disabled=false");
    });
}
function onRemove(e, Id) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("CartRemove", "Home")/' + Id;
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $(".ref").load("Detail .ref");
        $(".t").find("a[id*='rbutton_" + Id + "']").attr("disabled", false).attr("onClick", "this.disabled=true");
    });
}
```

This is code is helping to disable button but giving issue above I have written

```
$(".t").find("a[id*='rbutton_" + Id + "']").attr("disabled", "disabled").attr("onClick", "this.disabled=false");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have following ways of doing this type of structure.
If your rows are fixed you can either split your rows in two parts and render them in separate table.

OR

You can render 6 TD tags instead of 2 and render two records on one row.

OR

It would personally suggest not to use TABLE and go for DIV structure where you will have more flexibility and structure will easily adjust as per rows of your dataset like following.

```
  <div>
                        @foreach (var item in this.Model.ServiceList)
                        {  
                            <div style="float:left;">
                                <div>
                                    <img class="i" src="@item.IconUrl" />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <span>@item.Services</span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#" id="rbutton_@item.Id" onclick="onClick(event, @item.Id)" class="btn btn-success bt">+ add</a>
                                </div>
                                <div><span class="fa fa-inr"></span><span>@Mobilappy.Models.Detail.Price(@item.Id)</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>                       
                        }

                </div>
```

You may need to add some more styles to align it properly. If you are open to use any third party CSS libraries, i would suggest to use Bootstrap and check "col-md-*" class which can do this task easily for you. 
You can also use beuty of CSS Tables with "display:table" , "display:table-cell","display-table-row" if you don't want to use third party CSS lib.

**EDIT**

The above answer is for the question you asked to fix Structure of your page. 
To fox issue which you just updated on your question.. you have to try following script

```
$(".t").find("a[id='rbutton_" + Id + "']").attr("disabled", "disabled").attr("onClick", "this.disabled=false");
```

Remove "*" as it will select all elements otherwise.

Comment: can you try $(".t").find("a[id='rbutton_" + Id + "']"). just remove the "*"

Comment: yes it working now thanks I have a one more question is
when i reload the page it will make all disable button active again how can i keep disable button on page refresh?

Comment: @Vikas it will automatically activated for click after page refreshed you don't need to do any extra stuff for this or in some case you need this you can do this like this way **$(function() {
  $(".t").find("a[id='rbutton_" + Id + "']").removeAttr("disabled")
});
** it will remove all disable attribute from all anchor buttons

Comment: I mean when user can click on f5 then I want to keep disable buttons which is added in cart.

Comment: It can be done it two different ways.. Either you store it in Session on server side, ow you have to store it in localStorage and restore values on form load. I would recommend to add a new question for it and we will answer that. Can you accept the answer now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Take and Skip. For the left side table use:

```
var tableRowsLeft = this.Model.ServiceList.Take(10);
```

And for the right table

```
var tableRowsRight = this.Model.ServiceList.Skip(10).Take(10);
```

But it depends on how many rows you might need to handle(this example is not very suitable if you have thousands of rows), and it would be best to handle that kind of logic in the Controller instead of in The View

Comment: Please check now question is updated. you answer is correct that I have did before posting question but I found that that was issue with `Script` which i have done in onClick event

Answer (score 1):

Just remove * from the Selection of element as below * use as **WILDCARDS** in jquery so it will disabled all anchor link which will match with this string **rbutton_1** so these anchor tags with this like **rbutton_10** and **rbutton_11**will be disabled.

See also this [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more information

```
$(".t").find("a[id='rbutton_" + Id + "']").attr("disabled", "disabled").attr("onClick", "this.disabled=false");
```